# printing in methods vs printing in the main/driver class

Tags: methods, loops

I'm fairly new to programming and am currently creating a blackjack game in Java.

I've progressed quite well, although could use some pointers with regards to the best way to implement a method.

At various points during a game of blackjack it's important to show the user what cards are in their hand. I have a PlayerHand class and a method that returns a card at index i as a string.

```
public String displayCard (int i)
{
    return hand.get(i).getCard();
}
```

'hand' is an ArrayList representing the hand and the .getCard() method on the card is as follows...

```
public String getCard ()
{
    return "The "+mCardValueName+" of "+mCardSuit;
}
```

This all seems well and good for returning the card at index i in a players hand, however what should I do if I want to display the entire hand?

I was thinking to do something like the following....

```
public void displayHand ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(displayCard(i));
    }
}
```

So calling the displayCard() method within the displayHand() method in a loop and printing.

Is this good programming practice to loop and print in a method? I don't want to write for loops in the main class each time I want to display the players cards in hand. Also, is there a way to easily return *multiple* Strings from a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good programming practice, because you are separating the functionality of printing the retrieved card from actually retrieving the card from the *deck* /object.

It's fine that you have a for loop that prints everything, it doesn't matter whether it's in the *main* or in the *displayHand*. What you *would not* want to do is print inside of the *getHand*, because that would mix the functionality of your methods and might make your program unclear or difficult to use.

Additionally, you can return multiple Strings from your method without a problem. Consider returning an array of Strings (multiple Strings). The function stub would be:

```
public String[] getCards()
{
    // code
}
```

Note: It's always good to separate the user/operator interface from the API classes being utilized in your application.

Comment: Thanks StevieV. Ah yes forgot I could just return an array of strings. Would I be correct in thinking my solution might still be preferable in this scenario as even if I return all the cards in a string array in a method, I would still need to write a loop each time I want to display them all in my main class?

Comment: Right, you would still need some kind of a loop to parse each element of the array. You could do this nicely with a "foreach" loop if you wanted to, or as you said a "for" loop.